# Issues with Grade Build

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Everytime I try to create a new Activity, i get this error:

```
Error:(28, 13)Failed to resolve: com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5.+
```

Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `.+` at the end of this line:

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5.+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
```